# XML Regular expression for excluding a Word called "County" in the input string and can accept any word/number/empty space

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I need help in XML code for Regular expression. My code should not accept these words County|county|COUNTY|Cnty|CNTY|cnty|Parish|PARISH|parish. Due to some XML limitation its hard to sove the XML regular expression I'm using Version 1.0 in both XML and XSD files. Please help me

```
<xs:pattern value=".*[a-zA-Z0-9].*[^(?!county|COUNTY|County|Cnty|cnty|CNTY|Parish|PARISH|parish).$]"/> 

<xs:pattern value=".*[a-zA-Z0-9].*[^(?!county|COUNTY|County|Cnty|cnty|CNTY|Parish|PARISH|parish).$]"/>
```

Expected results: Fairfax city parkway

Error with code: Fairafax city (This should match with my regular expression)

Comment: Can you give more examples of what your expected results and the error you're getting is?

Comment: My expected result is : Test1 Fairfax city parkway  ... This can accept any character string except the word "COUNTY" or "PARISH" or "CNTY" with all possibilities.

Comment: This is challenging to do in XSD.  See the duplicate link for details.

Comment: My XML should through up an error when the Input String is Like this:  Faifax county or County Fairfax or Fairfax county City or Fairfax PARISH or Parish Fairfax or fairfax parish city.

Comment: Hi I tried all the possibilties The code works fine in online tester when it comes to XSD validator tools some of the sysmbols wont accept

Comment: kjhughes : Can you please explain how it works with the duplicate

Comment: I am still working on this issue not a dublicate